# How can I prove that two finite elementary equivalent structures are isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

For every two elementary equivalent structures $M$ and $N$, s.t. $M$ and $N$ are finite with same cardinality $k$, how can I prove that they are isomorphic?

Of course if $M$ and $N$ are isomorphic they are elementary equivalent, but the reverse does not hold for infinite structures.

Thanks

Comment: As a hint, first show that for any finite structure $M$ in a *finite* language, there is a single sentence $\mu$ characterizing $M$ up to isomorphism (that is, $N\models\mu$ iff $N\cong M$). Then, tweak this idea to give the weaker result in your question for *infinite* languages.

Comment: It may also help to consider a special case, say the case of finite groups.

Comment: Hint for Noah Schwebers hint:  for the case of an infinite language consider https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1245353/show-for-any-language-l-two-l-structures-m-and-n-are-elementarily-equivalent-iff?rq=1